# Which database is used when play test?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

My application.conf:

```
### default #conf/evolutions/default/1.sql
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"

### test  #conf/evolutions/test/1.sql
db.test.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.test.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

I run `run` command in  `play` console, is db.default used?

When I run `test` command in `play` console, is still db.default used? How can I use db.test when I run `test`?

And when will `conf/evolutions/default/1.sql` and `#conf/evolutions/test/1.sql` be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use the default database. Specifying the environment in the parameter key was a Play1 specific feature.